# jQuery: select elements by style attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, attributes, selector

I'm trying to select list of elements which have its style attribute begins with "color".

My HTML:

```html
 <div id='idd' style="color: red; border: 1px solid black">abc</div>
```

My query:

```js
var list= $('[style|="color"]');
```

var list is null after querying (1).

```js
var list= $('[style*="color"]');
```

but statement (2) works well,
and

```js
$('#idd').attr('style')
```

returns exact `color: red; border: 1px solid black`

I know that I should find elements by name or id attribute or just query if "color" appears in style (no need to match the position).
But I realy wonder why it doesn't work as my expectation.

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0):

`[style|="color"]` doesn't match because `color` isn't followed by dash and isn't an exact match.

> [att|=val] Represents an element with the att attribute, its value
>   either being exactly "val" or beginning with "val" immediately
>   followed by "-" (U+002D).

[SPEC](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors)

> I'm trying to select list of elements which have its style attribute
>   begins with "color"

So use:

```
var list= $('[style^="color"]');
```